# strange error message in a complex, but legal Perl one-liner

Tags: perl

```
>perl -e '$_ = q(t b[\)sizeof];); s/(t?(\w)(?:\s(\w))?\s(\w)(\[([^\]]+)\]))/eval $1/e'
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near ")sizeof"
    (Missing operator before sizeof?)
```

This is legal Perl, then why the error message?  I have the latest Perl.

This is an SSCCE ; any one character less and the error message does not appear.

Comment: Side note: "I have the latest Perl" is not objective information. You should instead say "I have Perl version v5.16" (or whatever), which is not only objective, but can be understood by someone reading the question later on.

Comment: Thank you Sir may I have another.

Comment: Sure, why not. Another common one is: "I am a Perl newbie". This can both include someone with years of programming experience, and someone who just opened a command prompt for the first time yesterday.

Comment: Well, this is getting OT, but I would not say "I am so-and-so".  That is judgemental, and I only apply judgement to ideas, not people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Perl code is valid, but you are trying to `eval` a string which is not valid Perl code. When I run this code and swap `eval` for `print`, it prints the string:

```
t b[)sizeof]
```

Now if I try and run this as Perl code I get:

```
> perl -we't b[)sizeof]'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ")sizeof"
        (Missing operator before sizeof?)
Unquoted string "sizeof" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "[)"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

(You should always use warnings `-w`, even with one-liners)

This code does exactly what your evaluation is trying to do: It's trying to run that string as Perl code, and it fails because that string is not valid Perl code.

Also you should be *careful* when using `eval`, as it can do unexpected and catastrophical things to your computer. Usually, this kind of double evaluation is written using two of the `/e` modifiers, e.g.:

```
s/.../.../ee
```

Which is a bit more convenient than

```
s/.../eval .../e
```

Comment: Sorry, that was stupid question.  I've been working all night and should probably go to sleep before I ask any more idiotic questions.

Comment: @MarkGaleck Well, as some would say, there are no stupid questions. :) But perhaps a good idea nonetheless, especially when trying out `eval`.

Comment: I personally avoid `s/.../.../ee` since code generation and evaluation should be a giant visible red flag, not a tiny unsearchable `e`.